# color dots with gradient based on value of each dot

Tags: angular, d3.js

I make a bunch of dots, each dot has a certain value (between 0 and 1), i want to color each dot based on that value  e.g. 0 = grey, 1 = bright red and anything in between is a mix of these colors

i found this fiddle which is what i want, but i am unable to find out how i could implement it in my code

https://codepen.io/SitePoint/pen/rLyKLG

my code:

```js
 drawExpression() {
    let data : number[] = [];
    const colorMap = d3.interpolateRgb(
      d3.rgb('#6c6d6b'),
      d3.rgb('#ff0034')
    );
    var svgContainer = d3.select("body").append("svg")
      .attr("width", 1000)
      .attr("height", 1000);

    //draws dots
    for (let i = 0; i < this.cell[1].length; i++) {
      let x = this.cell[1][i].xCoordinate * 5 + 250;
      let y = this.cell[1][i].yCoordinate * 5 + 250;
      data.push(this.cell[1][i].expression);


      var circle = svgContainer.append("circle")
        .attr("cx", x)
        .attr("cy", y)
        .attr("r", 2)
        .style("fill", (d)=> {
          return colorMap(d)
        })

    }
  }
```

Comment: `d3.rgb` accepts CSS color names: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/EzzJdG?editors=1010

Comment: thanks, but that's not really the part i'm stuck on.

Comment: Ok, now I see your code. The problem is quite simple: there is no data binding here. Google *"d3 data binding"* and you'll find several tutorials.

Comment: thank you, i fixed it by using ```svgContainer.selectAll("circle")
        .data(data)
        .enter()
        .append("circle")
```

if you want, you can post the answer and i will accept it.  Just 1 more question, is there a way for me to specify the colors the gradient is allowed to go through? because now it shows blue,green, etc. in between grey and red. And i just want grey,red, and shades of faded red in between.